# git supports windows authentication. but how to use it without user interaction?

Tags: git, tfs, cruisecontrol.net

Git for windows is able to authenticate using windows authentication (NTLM): just press enter twice when asked for user credentials.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\CruiseControl.NET\server\MyGitProject>git clone http://cgdlyovm0161:8080/tfs/TAHAA/DT_FWK_GIT/_git/Cegid.Net%20Trunk WorkingDirectory
Cloning into 'WorkingDirectory'...
Username for 'http://cgdlyovm0161:8080':
Password for 'http://cgdlyovm0161:8080':
remote:
remote:                    fTfs
remote:                  fSSSSSSSs
remote:                fSSSSSSSSSS
remote: TSSf         fSSSSSSSSSSSS
remote: SSSSSF     fSSSSSSST SSSSS
remote: SSfSSSSSsfSSSSSSSt   SSSSS
remote: SS  tSSSSSSSSSs      SSSSS
remote: SS   fSSSSSSST       SSSSS
remote: SS fSSSSSFSSSSSSf    SSSSS
remote: SSSSSST    FSSSSSSFt SSSSS
remote: SSSSt        FSSSSSSSSSSSS
remote:                FSSSSSSSSSS
remote:                  FSSSSSSs
remote:                    FSFs    (TM)
remote:
remote:  Microsoft (R) Visual Studio (R) Team Foundation Server
remote:
Receiving objects: 100% (11908/11908), 165.99 MiB | 10.75 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (5227/5227), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

But.. How to skip the request for user credentials?, i.e. the part

```
Username for 'http://cgdlyovm0161:8080':
Password for 'http://cgdlyovm0161:8080':
```

The aim here is to use the credentials of the current user, without neither any interaction nor any configuration file.

Comment: Great question.  Unfortunately, even the git-credential-winstore helper won't save empty username/password and won't help in this scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer was obvious.

```
git clone http://:@cgdlyovm0161:8080/tfs/TAHAA/DT_FWK_GIT/_git/Cegid.Net%20Trunk WorkingDirectory
```

Notice the `:@` token between http:// and the hostname.

Comment: Hey, this isn't overly obvious to me. What does the ```:@``` do?

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was prompted for login details because I installed `Git for Windows` 2.25.1 with the option `Enable Git Credential Manager` unticked.

Ticking `Enable Git Credential Manager` during the installation solved the problem and I don't have to provide credentials anymore.